# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process"

Tags: h2, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to follow the direction to setup the Virgo sample project greenpages ( http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/greenpages-documentation-2.4.0.RELEASE/docs/html/ch02s03.html ).  When i execute the data script I get an exception.

The database is started like so:

```
start java -cp ";C:\Users\flowersj\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.3.161\h2-1.3.161.jar" 
    org.h2.tools.Server
```

The script to insert data that fails on this line:

```
java -cp ";C:\Users\flowersj\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.3.161\h2-1.3.161.jar"
    org.h2.tools.RunScript 
    -url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/greenpages-db/greenpages 
    -user greenpages -password pass -script db.sql
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-161]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.getExceptionAlreadyInUse(FileLock.java:435)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:332)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:128)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:539)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:219)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:214)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:538)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:109)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:373)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:267)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:312)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:140)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:68)
```

Comment: Well, in that case the database is most likely already in use, just like the error message says...

Answer (score 1):

I found that I cannot have the Virgo server running at the same time as I execute the data.bat script.  I thought that it was started in a mode that supported multiple connections.